# how to adjust margin and padding using width with percentage?

Tags: html, css, margin

So I want to achieve this using css and html

[image]

So I wrote this code that sets the width of each box to 33.33%

```css
/* Base style */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
div > div {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
.dummy_text {
  clear: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* Top right paragraphs*/

#chiken {
  float: right;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#beef {
  float: right;
  background-color: indianred;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#sushi {
  float: right;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* Desktop */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-dsk-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <h1>Our menu</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-2 col-mbl-1">
    <p id="chiken">Chicken
      <p>
        <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-2 col-mbl-1">
    <p id="beef">Beef
      <p>
        <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-1 col-mbl-1">
    <p id="sushi">Sushi
      <p>
        <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

The thing is that I need spacing between paragraphs, so what I though was to add some margin-left to the boxes, the thing is that when I add 10px, the result is that one of the three boxes goes to a new line, but I need the three in the same line.

This is what I did to add the margin, I modify the div > div part like this:

```
div > div {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

And then result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use % values for all your layout widths.
Use **:last-child** to set the margin of the right div to zero.

```
div > div {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%
}

div > div:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
}

/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-dsk-3 {
        float: left;
        width: 32%;
    }
}
```

Here's a codepen:http://codepen.io/prime8/pen/LRympm

Answer (score 1):

Use `calc` for with

```
.col-dsk-3 {
    float: left;
    width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.col-dsk-3:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

But I suggest you use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead

Answer (score 1):

When adding the `margin-left: 10px` to each paragraph you are making their widths larger than 33.33% which results in being greater than 100% pushing the last paragraph down.

Like all things in CSS, there is a couple of different ways you can solve this, but the easiest and most direct answer to your question is using the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) CSS function. The calc function calculates a numerical value in CSS using basic math operations.

Using the calc function you can then set the width of each paragraph to be:

```
width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
```

Which will result in a 100% fit.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do about this.
1 - Use calc to reduce the width of elements currently set to 33.33% by 10px, and use 10px margin:

```
.col-dsk-3 {
    float: left;
    width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

2 - Wrap the content of your columns in another element, and apply a padding to your columns:

```
<div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-2 col-mbl-1">
  <div class="column-content">
    <p id="chiken">Chicken<p>
    <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit....</p>
  </div>
</div>

.column-content {
    background-color: gray;
}

.col-dsk-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: none;
}
```

3 - use flexbox instead of floats for your columns. Remove the floats and the `width: 33.33%`, and add:

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
.col-dsk-3 {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use percentages to define the width, but add absolute values to the margins. Your widths add up to (almost) 100%, yet you add more margins, resulting in more than 100%, therefore to a value that is bigger than the space that is available.
Adjust your margins to use percentages as well and make sure you end up with 100% or less.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. To use additional `div` wrapper in HTML.
This way has a good compatibility.

```css
/* Base style */

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* NOTE: `.row > div > div` is better than `div > div > div` */
div > div > div {    /* changed */
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}

.row > div > div {   /* changed */  
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.dummy_text {
    clear:right;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Top right paragraphs*/

#chiken {
    float: right;
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#beef {
    float: right;
    background-color: indianred;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#sushi {
     float: right;
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-dsk-3 {
        float: left;
        width: 33.33%;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our menu</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-2 col-mbl-1">
        <div>
            <p id="chiken">Chicken<p>
            <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-2 col-mbl-1">
        <div>
            <p id="beef">Beef<p>
            <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-dsk-3 col-tbl-1 col-mbl-1">
        <div>
            <p id="sushi">Sushi<p>
            <p class="dummy_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```